# Second Try on Joining 3 tables using AWK/SED/

Tags: sed, awk, paste

So, my last question I wasn't quite specific enough, and although I'm alot closer, I am still having problems with joining my 3 text tables in a way that makes sense.  Now, in more detail here they are:

**T1_01 = Table 1**

```
 No  Object     CCmax    Vhel    cont  noise    Mag1  
001  _P10644    0.816  123.04  2450.3   74.2   15.34    
002   Parked  -99.900  -99.90   -99.9  -99.9  -99.90  
003  _P10569    0.791  146.30  2650.7   75.3   15.50   
004  _P10769    0.641  141.49   482.7   30.2   16.42  
005  _P10572    0.848  138.15  2161.4   46.3   15.85
```

**T1_02 = Table 2**

```
Fibrel       Namel  Typel  Pivl         RAl        DECl   Magl  
   001   F1_P10644      P     1  4.89977691  -0.5104696   15.3  
   002      Parked      N     2  4.88965087  -0.4904939    0.0   
   003   F1_P10569      P     3  4.89642427  -0.5099916   15.5  
   004   F1_P10769      P     4  4.90643599  -0.5112466   16.4  
   005   F1_P10572      P     5  4.89644907  -0.5105655   15.8
```

**T1_03 = Table 3**

```
Name                       RA                 DEC  Imag       Fieldname fiber      RV    eRV                                                               
F1_P10644   4.899776910023531  -0.510469633262908 15.34   100606F1red   001  122.47   2.94  
F1_P10569   4.896424277974554  -0.509991655454702 15.50   100606F1red   003  145.55   2.72  
F1_P10769   4.906435995618358  -0.511246644149622 16.42   100606F1red   004  116.28  12.87  
F1_P10572   4.896449076194342  -0.510565529409031 15.85   100606F1red   005  136.15   3.01
```

The table output I am hoping for is:

`T1_0123` (joined on column 1 `T1_01`, column 1 `T1_02`, and column 6 `T1_03`)

```
 No   Object  CCmax    Vhel    cont   noise    Mag1  Fibrel      Namel   Typel  Pivl         RAl        DECl   Magl       Name                   RA                  DEC    Imag     Fieldname fiber      RV    eRV
```

where line1 =

```
001  _P10644  0.816  123.04  2450.3    74.2   15.34     001  F1_P10644       P     1  4.89977691  -0.5104696   15.3  F1_P10644    4.899776910023531   -0.510469633262908   15.34   100606F1red    001  122.47   2.94
```

and line2 =

```
002   Parked  -99.9   -99.9   -99.9   -99.9   -99.9     002  Parked          N     2  4.88965087  -0.4904939    0.0  -99.9        -99.9               -99.9                -99.9         -99.9  -99.9   -99.9  -99.9
```

So that -99.9 was written into the line that had no match for the 3rd file.

Now I CAN join the files if I skip the header with:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 |awk 'NR != 1' <T1_02 |awk 'NR != 1'<T1_01 >T1_021

join -1 1 -2 6 T1_021 |awk 'NR != 1'<T1_03 >T1_0123
```

However this ONLY prints the results of the first table listed in the join, so I don't get all columns I need.  Likewise if I want all 3 tables I 'could' do:

```
paste T1_01 T1_02 T1_03
```

Except, in this case my `T1_03` will not match as it is missing several values.  So what I am looking for is a way to say something like:

```
for all i in files T1_01,T1_02,T1_03
  if T1_01 $1 == T1_02 $2 == T1_03 $6 
    # then print T1_01[i] T1_02[i] T1_03[i] \n, 
  else 
    # print T1_01[i] T1_02[i] -99.9 (for all blanks)
  fi
done
```

Or conversely, use my join statement above and print all lines in BOTH tables joined, or perhaps some sort of paste | join?? Not sure about that last idea as I haven't found anything that really works yet.

Additionally I can do put the -99.9 in later with:

```
sed -i -e 's/                        / 99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9/' T1_0123
```

And I can manually add headers as well, so the main problem is getting the right paste result.

Hopefully I have phrased the question better this time, thanks everyone, for helping a new bash user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doing what you want. The script assumes your data to be in data1, data2 and data3. It writes all this data into a temporary file while tagging it according to origin (lines from data1 are appended "A", etc...). It also adds the index on which to join to the beginning of lines from data3. Then the data is sorted to group corresponding lines.
Then awk is used to print corresponding records and fill in placeholder data for missing entries from data3.

You should be able to adjust to your needs if that's not exactly what you wanted - otherwise drop a comment :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR > 1 {print $0, "A"}' data1 >tmp
awk 'NR > 1 {print $0, "B"}' data2 >>tmp
awk '{print $6, $0, "C"}' data3 >>tmp

sort -nk1,1 tmp | \
  awk '
    function printDATA() {
        print DATA["A"], DATA["B"], DATA["C"]
        DATA["C"] = "-99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9"
        DATA["C"] = DATA["C"] " -99.9 -99.9 -99.9"
    }
    $1 != last && NR > 1{printDATA()}
    {
        m = $NF; $NF = ""; last = $1;
        if(m == "C") {$1 = ""}
        DATA[m] = $0
    }
    END {printDATA()}
  '
```

Comment: Nice! This does indeed put it together nicely, just a quick follow up, since I wanted to save this as makesgood.sh and run it as:     makesgood.sh data1 data2 data3 ... I just put in $1, $2, $3 above for data1 data2 and data3 respectively. Thanks Theodros!

Comment: A quick aside, while the above does work, for some reason on lists of files it does not compile, i.e. .... makesgood.sh $(cat d1) $(cat d2) $(cat d3) > bigfile

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your asking? If d1, d2 and d3 are existing files then the $(cat d*) subshells will return the contents of those files! The final command line that is used to call makesgood.sh looks then: `makesgood.sh this is possible contents of d1 ....etc > bigfile` were makesgood.sh would try to open the files `this`, `is`, `possible` which presumably fails.... If d* are not existing files then cat will already complain

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant that I have a lists of data1,data2,data3 files=d1,d2,d3. The solution is to do ... paste d1 d2 d3 > list ... then ...OIFS="${IFS}",NIFS=$'\n',IFS="${NIFS}" so that the carriage return divides the file ... then just .... for line in $(cat list); do IFS="${OIFS}"; makesgood.sh $line >>bigfile; IFS="${NIFS}"; done . Thanks Theodros!